# What setting is enabled? I cannot move the bone, but only rotate it

Tags: animation

I'm new to Blender. I am making a model from a video tutorial. And when I entered the pose mode, I probably pressed something, and now I cannot move the nodes, but only rotate. Please tell me how to turn off this stuff. =(

[image: My problem]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (armature only)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You're turned o a gizmo and enabled axis in the armature's Viewport Display settings.

Comment: No, i am asking not about axis. When i try move any node in _pose mode_, the circle appears and i can only rotation the node, but not move.  https://i.imgur.com/S5Zi8sU.png

Comment: Here is a model. https://pasteall.org/media/b/b/bb4e77e533ab30e4ac2bd7b51c4cc59f.blend

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. This is normal behavior for this bone structure. The *LowerLeg.R* bone is a child of c and you parented them with the *Connected* option. Therefore you cannot move it.

Furthermore, *LowerLeg.R* has an *IK Bone Constraint* (yellow color) which limits its movement and the rotation of the *LowerLeg.R*.

Use the control bone *IKTarget.R* at the heel to move the leg.

[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: For a combination of IK and FK have a look here: https://youtu.be/5RMtkdWgZ8g

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.)